# Apollo subscriptions JWT authentication

Tags: authentication, jwt, apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

I am using Robin Wieruch's fullstack boilerplate but it is missing authentication for subscriptions. It uses JWT token for sessions and it is working fine for http but for ws auth is completely missing.

I need to pass user trough context for subscriptions as well, I need session info in subscriptions resolver to be able to decide weather I should fire subscription or not.

I did search Apollo docs, I saw I should use `onConnect: (connectionParams, webSocket, context)` function, but there is no fully functional fullstack example, I am not sure how to pass JWT from client to be able to get it in webSocket object.

Here is what I have so far:

Server:

```js
import express from 'express';
import {
  ApolloServer,
  AuthenticationError,
} from 'apollo-server-express';

const app = express();

app.use(cors());

const getMe = async req => {
  const token = req.headers['x-token'];

  if (token) {
    try {
      return await jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET);
    } catch (e) {
      throw new AuthenticationError(
        'Your session expired. Sign in again.',
      );
    }
  }
};

const server = new ApolloServer({
  introspection: true,
  typeDefs: schema,
  resolvers,
  subscriptions: {
    onConnect: (connectionParams, webSocket, context) => {
      console.log(webSocket);
    },
  },
  context: async ({ req, connection }) => {
    // subscriptions
    if (connection) {
      return {
        // how to pass me here as well?
        models,
      };
    }

    // mutations and queries
    if (req) {
      const me = await getMe(req);

      return {
        models,
        me,
        secret: process.env.SECRET,
      };
    }
  },
});

server.applyMiddleware({ app, path: '/graphql' });

const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
server.installSubscriptionHandlers(httpServer); 

const isTest = !!process.env.TEST_DATABASE_URL;
const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;


httpServer.listen({ port }, () => {
    console.log(`Apollo Server on http://localhost:${port}/graphql`);
});
```

Client:

```js
const httpLink = createUploadLink({
  uri: 'http://localhost:8000/graphql',
  fetch: customFetch,
});

const wsLink = new WebSocketLink({
  uri: `ws://localhost:8000/graphql`,
  options: {
    reconnect: true,
  },
});

const terminatingLink = split(
  ({ query }) => {
    const { kind, operation } = getMainDefinition(query);
    return (
      kind === 'OperationDefinition' && operation === 'subscription'
    );
  },
  wsLink,
  httpLink,
);

const authLink = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
  operation.setContext(({ headers = {} }) => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

    if (token) {
      headers = { ...headers, 'x-token': token };
    }

    return { headers };
  });

  return forward(operation);
});

const errorLink = onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError }) => {
  if (graphQLErrors) {
    graphQLErrors.forEach(({ message, locations, path }) => {
      console.log('GraphQL error', message);

      if (message === 'UNAUTHENTICATED') {
        signOut(client);
      }
    });
  }

  if (networkError) {
    console.log('Network error', networkError);

    if (networkError.statusCode === 401) {
      signOut(client);
    }
  }
});

const link = ApolloLink.from([authLink, errorLink, terminatingLink]);

const cache = new InMemoryCache();

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link,
  cache,
  resolvers,
  typeDefs,
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [connectionParams](https://github.com/apollographql/subscriptions-transport-ws#constructorurl-options-websocketimpl) to set the JWT from the client-side. Below is the code snippet using the angular framework:

```js
    const WS_URI = `wss://${environment.HOST}:${environment.PORT}${
      environment.WS_PATH
    }`;

    const wsClient = subscriptionService.getWSClient(WS_URI, {
      lazy: true,
      // When connectionParams is a function, it gets evaluated before each connection.
      connectionParams: () => {
        return {
          token: `Bearer ${authService.getJwt()}`
        };
      },
      reconnect: true,
      reconnectionAttempts: 5,
      connectionCallback: (error: Error[]) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }

        console.log('connectionCallback');
      },
      inactivityTimeout: 1000
    });

    const wsLink = new WebSocketLink(wsClient);
```

In your server-side, you are correct, using `onConnect` event handler to handle the JWT. E.g.

```js
  const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    context: contextFunction,
    introspection: true,
    subscriptions: {
      onConnect: (
        connectionParams: IWebSocketConnectionParams,
        webSocket: WebSocket,
        connectionContext: ConnectionContext,
      ) => {
        console.log('websocket connect');
        console.log('connectionParams: ', connectionParams);
        if (connectionParams.token) {
          const token: string = validateToken(connectionParams.token);
          const userConnector = new UserConnector<IMemoryDB>(memoryDB);
          let user: IUser | undefined;
          try {
            const userType: UserType = UserType[token];
            user = userConnector.findUserByUserType(userType);
          } catch (error) {
            throw error;
          }

          const context: ISubscriptionContext = {
            // pubsub: postgresPubSub,
            pubsub,
            subscribeUser: user,
            userConnector,
            locationConnector: new LocationConnector<IMemoryDB>(memoryDB),
          };

          return context;
        }

        throw new Error('Missing auth token!');
      },
      onDisconnect: (webSocket: WebSocket, connectionContext: ConnectionContext) => {
        console.log('websocket disconnect');
      },
    },
  });
```

server-side: https://github.com/mrdulin/apollo-graphql-tutorial/blob/master/src/subscriptions/server.ts#L72

client-side: https://github.com/mrdulin/angular-apollo-starter/blob/master/src/app/graphql/graphql.module.ts#L38

Comment: i did that, and i get different tokens from websocket and http? I get stale token  from previous session in websockets. Do you have any idea why that happens and how to clear header on websocket after sign out? https://prnt.sc/r1e5a8

Comment: HTTP request and websocket message should use the same JWT

Comment: Here is my code on client, and still i get wrong token (from last session) in websockets link. Do you have any idea about the cause? Where the wrong token could be persisted, i read the same token from local storage. https://github.com/nemanjam/audio-twitter/blob/master/client/src/index.js

Comment: I did some console logging, connectionParams() handler gets executed only on page refresh. Shouldn't it be executed more often?

Comment: subscriptions are working, but only after page refresh.